# How to have multiple <script src="url"> with src attribute in one HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

```js
var map;

  function initMapx() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'),{
      center: {lat:55.537664, lng:13.074432},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
```

```css
#myMap {
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<h4>Displaying Google map.</h4>


<script type="text/javascript" async defer
  src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMapx'>
</script>

<div id="myMap"></div>
```

This is the first map that i request from Google Map API from scirpt src="url" and it works fine.

```js
  function myCity() {
    var Athens = {lat:37.986259, lng:23.726772};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myPlace'), {zoom: 14, center: Athens});
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: Athens, map: map});
  }
```

```css
#myPlace {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<h4>Add a Google map with a marker.</h4>

<div id="myPlace"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" async defer
  src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myCity'>
</script>
```

This is the second map that i request from Google Map API from src attribute in the script tag in the HTML. When the second map loads the first map disappears. I think because the first script src="url" tag is overwritten by the second script src="url". I know i can put both maps in one code block. But i want to request them separately. Any way to have multiple script src="url" in one page?

Comment: Have you checked via console what happens on page or just guessing? Can you put everyting to one SOSnippet?

Comment: @Justinas Putting a working Maps API into a snippet would require disclosure of the OP's API Key; probably not something they should do...

Comment: Both maps work fine. But as soon as i put the second script src the first map disappear so it has to do with the scripts. They overwrite each other.

Comment: NB: The `type` attribute should be omitted when the value is `text/javascript`.

Comment: There are ways to have multiple maps in one page. But the main thing i want to know is, having multiple script src in one page.

Comment: Well, not with those `src`s, as you've discovered.

Comment: @HereticMonkey 1) You can provide a working code snippet without the API key - most of the Google Maps functionality will still work 2) You can provide a working code snippet by using the API key that Google has provided for use on SO and JSFiddle which you can find in many of my (and others') answers here on SO 3) A *non-working* code snippet with "YOUR_KEY" instead of the right key is always better than no code snippet and 4) If an API key is properly restricted, as per Google recommendations, you can share/expose it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 1):

Including multiple `<script>` elements in a page only causes problems if they try to create the same global variables … which is exactly what will happen if you try to include the Google Maps API in the same page twice.

So don't do that.

Write **one** callback function (currently you have two: `initMapx` and `myCity`) which creates **both** maps.

```
function createBothMaps() {
    initMapx();
    myCity();
}
```

and

```
<script async defer src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=createBothMaps'>
```

Comment: Yes. That can solve the problem. But i am curious if i can have multiple script src on one page. Is this possible?

Comment: @EliasAchilles — I refer you back to the first paragraph of this answer.